# Java named parameter's name (for Oracle JDBC function result)

Tags: java, jdbc, named-parameters

I'm going to call a function, and set some parameters by name, example:

```
    Connection c = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String query;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    try {
        c = DbUtils.getConnection();
        cs = c.prepareCall("{? = call get_proc_name(?, ?) }");
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        cs.setInt("in_proc_type", ProcTypes.SELECT);
        cs.setLong("in_table_id", tableId);
        // here I should use something like cs.registerOutParameter("result", OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        cs.execute();
```

PL/SQL function parameters are:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_proc_name
(
  in_proc_type IN NUMBER, /*1 - insert, 2 - update, 3 - delete, 4 - select*/
  in_table_name IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
  in_table_id IN NUMBER := NULL,
  in_table_type_id IN NUMBER := NULL,
  is_new IN NUMBER := 0
) RETURN VARCHAR2
```

The question is how to register result as an out parameter, and then get it from oracle to java?
I can register in/out parameters by name, because I know theirs names from function, but I don't know how go get function result, what variable name use for it.

Manuals describe only usage in/out params with procedures, not functions.

Oracle version: 11.1.0.6.0
Java version: 1.6.0_14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You register the function result as if it were the first parameter. Obviously, this shifts the numbering of the actual parameters.

Your already existing line

```
cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
```

is all it takes. After the call, get your result like this:

```
String result = cs.getString(1);
```

Comment: I got exception "The number of parameter names does not match the number of registered praremeters" on line with "cs.execute();" .... p.s. I've just forgotten to remove this line when posted the code.

Comment: IIRC you cannot mix positional and named parameters, you it seems like you have to use positional parameters for the whole statement, i.e. cs.setInt(2, ProcTypes.SELECT); cs.setLong(3, tableId);

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to use only indexes for settings parameters. Such code works as expected (mixing indexes and named parameters doesn't work; so, the problem of using named parameter for result variable could not be solved, imho):

```
            c = DbUtils.getConnection();
            cs = c.prepareCall("{? = call get_proc_name(in_proc_type => ?, in_table_id => ?) }");
            cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            cs.setInt(2, ProcTypes.SELECT);
            cs.setLong(3, tableId);
            cs.execute();
            String procName = cs.getString(1);
            cs.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

`CallableStatement` has a bunch of `registerXXX` methods that take index.

That's how you register the result.  It is parameter number 1.

In your case,

```
cs.registerOutParameter( 1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
```

**<SPECULATION>**
BTW, because you are using index for `result`, you may need to use index-oriented `setXXX` methods and provide a full parameter list.
**</SPECULATION>**

Comment: I got "Invalid column index" on line with cs.registerOutParameter( 0, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);