# Is it possible to call pl/sql function from jdbc and register the return value by name?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, oracle11g

I am able to call pl/sql functions, using call statements with the following syntax:

```
String call = "{ ? = call p_some_package.some_function( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }";
CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(call);
```

But then I have to pass arguments using their indexes, because I have to register the return value, which doesn't have a name:

```
cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
cs.setInt(2, someInteger);
...
```

However when calling procedures, I can provide parameter names, because there's no "nameless" out parameter, as there is with a function:

```
cs.setInt("param_name", param_value);
```

Oracle pl/sql reference states that for functions Oracle creates one additional OUT parameter which it returns. So my questions is: Is it possible to pass the name of this parameter or somehow assign a name to this parameter and use it to pass arguments to pl/sql functions from JDBC as I do for procedures?

*Similar question, no answer:*
[Java named parameter's name (for Oracle JDBC function result)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699891/java-named-parameters-name-for-oracle-jdbc-function-result)

Comment: Provide outline of your function to understand what exactly you mean by OUT parameter which do not have a name.

Comment: @Polppan: He means the return value.

Comment: Yes, already edited.

Comment: Yes you have [registerOutParameter(String parameterName,int sqlType)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter(java.lang.String,%20int))

Comment: But what's the name of the return value for functions?

Comment: `Name of return value` ?? it doesn't have a name.. will any function have a name for the value it return, in any language? It's just return type...

Comment: Name the title correctly before questioning!

Comment: It says a function, not a procedure. And with functions, as I am sure you know, you get the return value. So the question is valid.

Comment: @RahimMammadlee Unfortunately, Oracle supports OUT type for functions also. And even with the declaration of function we just mention `RETURN <sometype>` , like in any language. In case of a table function, it actually return a row and it have a name for every column and the default name would be `COLUMN_VALUE` , but it wont apply in your case.

Comment: @RahimMammadlee I doubt it would be possible to call a return value with a name. See the CallableSatement documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter(int,%20int)).

Comment: Since I cannot pass the return_value by name, I have to pass every other parameter by position, because I cannot mix them. If I do I get the exception: "The number of parameter names does not match the number of registered praremeters".

Comment: Is using positional parameters causing a problem, or would you just prefer to use names? Are you using the Oracle extensions (`oraclecallablestatement` etc.)? If so would be it be any more pleasant to call the function as a prepared statement instead, alias the call, and retrieve it by name from the result set? (You'd have to use the `:x` bind notation instead of `?` for the function arguments, of course...).

Comment: Please edit the question and provide a complete code example which produces the error noted above ("The number of parameter names does not match the number of registered praremeters"). Include both the PL/SQL function being called (at a minimum, provide it's specification) and the Java code which invokes it. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexPoole It doesn't cause any major problems, but I believe using names is less error-prone. I am not using Oracle extensions, but I'll look into that.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947754/getting-the-return-value-from-jdbc-mssql , looks to have the answer to your problem

Answer (score 6):

You can use anonymous block instead of "call" syntax in order to use named binding

Before use this approach, take a look at this post and make sure you do not fall in trouble inverting order of setXXX variables
http://info.michael-simons.eu/2012/07/23/oracle-jbdc-callablestatements-and-named-parameters/

```
@Test
public void testFunctionOrdered() throws SQLException {
    String sql = "begin :quotient := TEST_QUOTIENT(DIVIDEND => :numerator, DIVISOR => :denominator); end;";

    CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(sql);

    cs.registerOutParameter("quotient", Types.INTEGER);
    cs.setInt("numerator", 6);
    cs.setInt("denominator", 2);

    cs.execute();

    assertEquals(3, cs.getInt("quotient"));

}
```