# Oracle Stored Procedure JDBC call with named paramaters fails with 'Found Symbol >'

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, named-parameters, callable-statement

I got this Oracle stored procedure code calling another stored procedure:

```sql
PROCEDURE xyz_main (
  i_param_a IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'Y',
  i_param_b IN PERSON.NAME%TYPE
  i_param_c IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'BLA'
  o_return_msg OUT VARCHAR2
)
IS
  ...
BEGIN
  ...
END xyz_main;

PROCEDURE xyz_example (
  i_param_b IN PERSON.NAME%TYPE DEFAULT 'Ben'
  o_return_msg OUT VARCHAR2
)
IS
BEGIN
  xyz_main(
    i_param_b => i_param_b,
    i_param_c => 'Great',
    o_return_msg => o_return_msg
  );
END xyz_example;
```

Now my task is to call xyz_main by Java. I wrote this code:

```java
// Using question mark because later on the values will be provided by function parameters
// Question: is "o_return_msg => ?" correct, even if I don't provide an input value?
String statement = "BEGIN xyz_main(i_param_b => ?, i_param_c => ?, o_return_msg => ?); END;";  

try (Connection conn = getOraConnection();) {
  CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(statement);

  // cs.setString("i_param_a", "Y"); -- omitted because the default value should be used always
  cs.setString("i_param_b", "Ben");
  cs.setString("i_param_c", "Great"); // should overwrite the default value
  cs.registerOutParameter("o_return_msg", Types.VARCHAR);

  cs.execute();
} catch (Exception e) {
  ...
}
```

Running the code I get this Exception:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 47:
PLS-00103: Fand das Symbol ">" als eines der folgenden erwartet wurde: ..
```

In English:

```
PLS-00103: Found Symbol ">" but expected one of this: ..
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Does `BEGIN xyz_main(?, ?); END` work?

Comment: That's what my colleague recommended. I tried e.g. "{CALL xyz_main(<params>)}" as well .. same error.

Comment: Maybe your question was whether it works with indexed parameters .. yes this works. But then I cannot ommit parameters.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699891/java-named-parameters-name-for-oracle-jdbc-function-result/3700334#3700334) answer your question? He seems to use names for the prepareCall, but indexes for setting the values. [Christoph](https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_jdbc_parameter.html) too.

Answer (score 1):

I was assuming when using named parameters I always have to use the syntax 'par_name => ?'. This was the mistake.

It's no problem to write code like this:

```
//* don't work:
// String statement = "BEGIN xyz_main(i_param_b => ?, i_param_c => ?, o_return_msg => ?); END;";  // don't work
//* works:
String statement = "BEGIN xyz_main(?, ?, ?); END;"; 

try (Connection conn = getOraConnection();) {
  CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(statement);
  // cs.setString("i_param_a", "Y"); -- omitted because the default value should be used always
  cs.setString("i_param_b", "Ben");
  cs.setString("i_param_c", "Great"); // should overwrite the default value
  cs.registerOutParameter("o_return_msg", Types.VARCHAR);
  cs.execute();
  System.out.println(cs.getString("o_return_msg"));
  cs.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is very confusing indeed. So, either you have the names in `prepareCall` or in `setString`, but not in both?

Comment: To me it seems so. I found examples in some blogs with other options, but for now I didn't investigate if these examples were old or for other databases or whatever. The most important fact: it works :) I added I line in my answer to make it more clear in case somebody else has the same issue.

Comment: Very well. BTW, it is ok to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) your own answer to show other users that it is a good solution to the question.